# Creating custom form type using sonata form type as parent

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'd like to make my own custom form type of sonata_type_collection, but I'm having trouble doing it.

At first I made my own type class and registered it as a service:

```
class SonataTypeCollectionWithSearchType extends AbstractType {

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {      
        $builder->add($options['type_options']['stcwst_attribute'], 'sonata_type_collection',array('data_class' => $options['type_options']['stcwst_class']));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'sonata_type_collection_with_search';
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'sonata_type_collection';
    }
}
```

The service.yml:

```
services:
    sonata_type_collection_with_search:
        class: ASV\CoreBundle\Form\Type\SonataTypeCollectionWithSearchType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: sonata_type_collection_with_search }
```

In an UniversityAdmin class I added this to the formMapper:

```
->add('studycourses', 'sonata_type_collection_with_search', array(
                'type_options' => array('delete' => false,
                'stcwst_attribute' => 'studycourse',
            'stcwst_class' => 'ASV\UniversityBundle\Entity\University'
                ), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                'sortable' => 'position',
                ))
```

But now I'm getting this error:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getAdmin() on a
>   non-object in
>   vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-phpcr-admin-bundle/Sonata/DoctrinePHPCRAdminBundle/Form/Extension/CollectionTypeExtension.php
>   line 32

Any ideas what went wrong? Is it even possible to have sonata_type_collection as a parent?